# How to Optimize double lookup of a large table in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

Trying to optimize the table lookup. Typically for a size of 5000 entries its taking approx 7 minutes as the logic is not optimal and fetches the table element every time. is there a better way to do this?

example table (3 columns)

```
TaskID  TaskSubID   Status
34567       1.2       Done
34567       1.3       Open
34568       1.5       Open
34568       1.3       Finished
34569       1.2       Open
34569       1.4       Open
```

the task is to pick a task ID and check if anyone TaskSubID is of Status Done or finished. which essentially tells that any remaining Subtasks in that TaskID are simple efforts. The VBA script should add a 4th column providing the effort status. This is implemented using the following logic and it works well

```
    Public Sub Effort_Check()

        Dim LastCol, Lastrow, i, isFlag As Integer

        Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Activate
        LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            TaskID = Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("A" & i).Value
            isFlag = 0
            For j = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("A" & j) = TaskID Then
                    If Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("C" & j) = "Done" Then
                        isFlag = 1
                    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("C" & j) = "Finished" Then
                        isFlag = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next j

            If Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("C" & i) = "Open" Then
                If isFlag = 1 Then
                    Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Cells(i, LastCol + 1) = "Simple Effort"
                Else
                    Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Cells(i, LastCol + 1) = "New Effort"
                End If
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Cells(i, LastCol + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Range("C" & i)
            End If
        Next i

        ' Column Heading
        Sheets("Sheet1-sample").Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = "Effort"

    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. A `COUNTIFS` formula will do it.

Comment: can you please expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$C$2:$C$7,"Done"),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$C$2:$C$7,"Finished"))>0,"Simple Effort","New Effort")
```

Comment: the logic should be to find the taskID which is repeated and if it is open then mark it as new or simple effort based on the status of the similar task. Should we be changing the second argument from A5 to A2? i could not understand why A5 is used.   `=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$C$2:$C$7,"Done"),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$C$2:$C$7,"Finished"))>0,"Simple Effort","New Effort")`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I copied the formula from D5 by mistake. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

With a Pivot Table you can count by `Done`, `Finished` and `Open` for each `SubId` within each `TaskID` and filter on `TaskID` if to be selective. However I am unsure whether or not this would meet your requirement.